# Vanilla JS image slider using array to hold images not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a slider that will pull imgs from an array and then display them on a page so that more can be added later if needed. The problem I have is the last img in the array is showing but I cannot get the imgs to cycle thru with the click events I've created.

I've tried using a few different tutorials I've found online but most of them use an automatic slide function.

```
let current = 0;
let slider = document.getElementById('slide-show')
let slides = slider.childNodes;
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
let imgs = [
  '../img/img1.jpeg',
  '../img/img2.jpeg',
  '../img/img3.jpeg',
  '../img/img4.jpeg',
  '../img/img5.jpg'
];

function slideShow() {
  for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imgs[i];
    slider.appendChild(img)
  }
}

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function slideLeft(){
  if(current === 0) {
    current = slides.length;
    current--;
  }
});

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function slideRight() {
  if(current === slides.length) {
    current = 0;
    current++;
  }
})

slideShow();
```

```
CSS

#slide-show {
  position: relative;
}

 #slide-show img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

expected that function SlideLeft() will naturally allow you to move backwards in the img list. and of course arrowRight() will move it forward.

Comment: Your `current++` and `current--` statements should be outside of the if statement blocks in your event handlers. What exactly do you expect changing the value of current to do? Even once your event handler functions are working correctly, they will just change that value.

Comment: My though process was if I could tie current to the img that is displayed if the value is changed then based on the images being in an array the next array img should show up.

Comment: Have you consulted the web developer tools, in particular F12 > Console (in Firefox)? Errors in your script should appear there. Do make sure to first press F12, then click Console, then reload the page and then use the functions in your system.

Comment: Brandon, you'll likely make the images switch visibility by either manipulating styles or classes in your js. Using your existing code, you could add a method that ultimately sets the display, visibility, or z-index style of the images based on the value of current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codepen.io/levi_blodgett/pen/dEayLY

It seems to me like your DOM manipulation was a bit off from what I could tell, in this case I would say it is most effective to just check as well on event click rather than a for loop with each image constantly there.

In this case what we do it change the image instead of how you had it before which was have each image layered behind another, which may have been unintentional.

So instead of:

```
function slideShow() {
for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imgs[i];
    slider.appendChild(img)
  }
}
```

We have:

```
function slideShow(imgCount) {
    let currentImg = document.getElementById('img');
    currentImg.src = imgs[imgCount];
}
```

Which should be more clear what you are doing, setting the image to the current iteration that you have your event listeners iterate for you. The image is set into the HTML so it can edit the HTML instead of having to create an element on it's own, but you could do that if you wished, you'd just have to append after the left arrow probably which would be more difficult to follow and execute.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I want, thank you so much I was so stuck on doing it the way I envisioned I didn't even try and think of any other way to make it work. thank you very much!